# can anyone explain the syntax and function of below wso2 esb synapse.xml file. The the message mediation coccurs

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Can anyone explain how the message mediation occurs in the below XML code? Like what main sequence is, proxy service in-sequence is, what head mediator is doing here etc.. Why in some situation `endpoint` defined above in-sequence in proxy service?

What are parameters of proxy service and how to call a sequence using developer studio?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<registry provider="org.wso2.carbon.mediation.registry.ESBRegistry">
<parameter name="localRegistry">/</parameter>
<parameter name="cachableDuration">15000</parameter>
</registry>
<proxy name="CreditCardPaymentService"
      transports="https http"
      startOnLoad="true"
      trace="disable">
  <description/>
  <target>
     <inSequence>
        <property xmlns:xsd="http://ccps.services.esb.wso2.packt.com/xsd"
                  xmlns:m0="http://ccps.services.esb.wso2.packt.com"
                  name="symbol"
                  expression="//m0:doPayment/m0:paymentInfo/xsd:cardType"
                  scope="default"
                  type="STRING"/>
        <property xmlns:xsd="http://ccps.services.esb.wso2.packt.com/xsd"
                  xmlns:m0="http://ccps.services.esb.wso2.packt.com"
                  name="filepath"
                  expression="fn:concat('file:./repository/', //m0:doPayment/m0:paymentInfo/xsd:cardType)"/>
        <property name="EPR"
                  expression="get-property('registry',$ctx:filepath)"
                  type="STRING"
                  pattern="&lt;value&gt;(.+?)&lt;/value&gt;"
                  group="1"/>
        <header name="To" expression="get-property('EPR')"/>
        <sequence key="{$ctx:symbol}"/>
        <send/>
     </inSequence>
     <outSequence>
        <send/>
     </outSequence>
  </target>
  <publishWSDL>
     ...............................
  </publishWSDL>
</proxy>
<sequence name="VISA">
    <payloadFactory>
        <format>
            .....
        </format>
        <args>
            .....
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    </sequence>
    <sequence name="fault">
    <log level="full">
        <property name="MESSAGE" value="Executing default 'fault' sequence"/>
        <property name="ERROR_CODE" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
        <property name="ERROR_MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
    </log>
    <drop/>
    </sequence>
    <sequence name="AMEX">
    <payloadFactory>
        <format>
            .....
        </format>
        <args>
            ......
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    </sequence>
    <sequence name="main">
    <in>
        <log level="full"/>
        <filter source="get-property('To')" regex="http://localhost:9000.*">
        <send/>
        </filter>
    </in>
    <out>
        <send/>
    </out>
    <description>The main sequence for the message mediation</description>
    </sequence>
    </definitions>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If some one call your CreditCardPaymentService proxy service the message flow inside the proxy hit the inSequence, then:

1. In symbol property, you get the value of the xpath = //m0:doPayment/m0:paymentInfo/xsd:cardType result applied in the incoming  message.
2. In filepath property, you get the result of concat the string "file:./repository/" with the xpath result of //m0:doPayment/m0:paymentInfo/xsd:cardType
3. In EPR property you get the content value of the filepath, inside the ESB or EI internal registry.
4. The To header is set to the ERP value.
5. You call a dynamic sequence using the symbol property value..For example if the symbol value equal to "A", you call a sequence with the name equal to "A"
   In this proxy you have a VISA sequence and a AMEX sequence.
6. Both sequences create a new payload message using the payloadfactory mediator.
7. After the right sequence is called, the send mediator send the message to the header "To" value destination.
8. The response message hit the outSequence and it´s send it to the the proxy client.